# Content based recommender in mahout

Tags: java, csv, matrix, mahout, similarity

I am trying to build a content based recommender in mahout. I am aware that mahout doesn't support it directly, so I used item based recommender but with my own pre-computer similarity matrix as follows:
I built my own similarity matrix between features of items and saved it as "similar.csv" file, here is the code to build the recommender based on items features and their similarities:

```
public class MyRecommenderBuilderB implements RecommenderBuilder {

    public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel dataModel)
            throws TasteException {
        Collection<GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity> correlations = 
                  new ArrayList<GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity>();


        //reading similarities file and add to itemSimilarity matrix
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("similars.csv"));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {             
                String[] values = line.split(",", -1);
                try{
                    //System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(values[0])+"  "+ Integer.parseInt(values[1])+"  "+ Double.parseDouble(values[2]));
                    correlations.add(new GenericItemSimilarity.ItemItemSimilarity(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), Double.parseDouble(values[2])));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                System.out.print("Found one \n");
                //bw.write(values[0].hashCode()+ "," + values[1].hashCode() + "," + 4 + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            //here is where to specify the correlations between items(based on features)    
        ItemSimilarity itemSimilarity  =  new GenericItemSimilarity(correlations);
        return new GenericItemBasedRecommender(dataModel,itemSimilarity);
    }}
```

But, whenever I use the above recommender and then try to find the RMSE like this:

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("/path/to/dataset.csv"));
RecommenderEvaluator evaluator = new AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator();
RecommenderBuilder builder = new MyRecommenderBuilderB();
double result = evaluator.evaluate(builder, null, model, 0.9, 1.0);
System.out.println(result);
```

I always get the same result, regardless of what similarity matrix I provide in the "BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("similars.csv"));" line.
So, why doesn't it take the similarties I provide in the file and always evaluate based on users (seems like)?
I traced the code of MyRecommenderBuilderB and it seems that it works ok, and takes the file. but I think the problem in the evaluate function itself, how can I calculate the RMSE with item based recommender?
thanks